# python module current path is wrong on vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, path, pycharm

i used ./ to accses my current path for my python module its perfectly work with pycharm but when i try to run it on Vscode, its consider my current path as C:\user\user
my module is not even in my C drive

for example i run this code :

---

```
import pathlib
varname = pathlib.Path().resolve()
print(varname)
```

---

and i got 2 diffrent outputs

in vs code i got: C:\Users\User
and in pycharm its : P:\programing\wtong-path

By the way i specify the module locations in pycharm but there is no such option for vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to change the current working directory on VSC by the following code:

```
import os
os.chdir('your path here')
```

I believe this won't give any output but your path would change.